# Convert image.Image to image.NRGBA

Tags: image, go

When I call `png.Decode(imageFile)` it returns a type `image.Image`. But I can't find a documented way to convert this to an `image.NRGBA` or `image.RGBA` on which I can call methods like `At()`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with type assertions, but when I tried that I got the error: `impossible type assertion: image.NRGBA does not implement image.Image (At method has pointer receiver)`

Comment: you should do a type assertion for a pointer to NRGBA: `i2 = i1.(*image.NRGBA)`, since the pointer type implements the image interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need to "convert" the image type, and just want to extract the underlying type from the interface, use a "type assertion":

```
if img, ok := i.(*image.RGBA); ok {
    // img is now an *image.RGBA
}
```

Or with a type switch:

```
switch i := i.(type) {
case *image.RGBA:
    // i in an *image.RGBA
case *image.NRGBA:
    // i in an *image.NRBGA
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I got an `impossible type assertion` error when I tried `i.(image.RGBA)` but `i.(*image.RGBA)` followed by dereferencing `i` works. Clearly there's some stuff I need to learn about pointers in type assertions.

Comment: @Andy: why do you need to dereference it? Just keep the pointer.

Comment: I have functions which accept `image.NRGBA` arguments. Perhaps I should redesign them to accept pointers though. It seems sensible to pass images by reference.

Comment: @Andy, you'll never want any function to take an `image.NRGBA`; at minimum use `*image.NRGBA`. However, much better (*if* you don't need low level access to a specific pixel format) is to just use `image.Image` (your question only mentions needing `At` which is part of that interface). If you need to be able to set pixels, then use a [`draw.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Image) argument (which adds a `Set` method).

Comment: @DaveC: the `At` and `Set` methods aren't great for bulk operations. It's very slow to go through the interface, dereference, and return value conversions for every pixel. Large image manipulations require direct access to the `Pix` slice. (though that is probably implied by your caveat, I just wanted to make sure it was clear to someone new).

Comment: @JimB, true and definitely worth mentioning! IMO from an API point of view it's still best to accept an `image.Image` (or `draw.Image`) rather than a specific image format. If the code needs fast pixel access, it can use a type switch to special case access to common `Pix` members (like what the draw package does itself). Depending on the what's being done and the size of the image it can be reasonable to work with a specific underlying type and if a type assertion on the input `image.Image` fails use `image/draw` to semi-efficiently copy it to the required type and work with that.

Comment: Of course I'm talking about exported APIs; if you're writing code that is non-exported or otherwise knows it will *never* need to deal with more than a single image format, then it's fine to just use `*image.NRGBA` (or whatever underlying type is appropriate).

Comment: Yes, I keep hearing about how it's not efficient to iterate over pixels with `At` and `Set`, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Is there a way I can specify a kernel operation like I would in something such as OpenGL. Or should I just be iterating over `Pix` using a pointer, like in C?

Comment: @Andy: yes, you iterate over `Pix` (though there's no pointer involved here, you just use a for loop and index into Pix)

Answer (score 6):

The solution to the question in the title, how to *convert* an image to `image.NRGBA`, can be found [in the Go Blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-imagedraw-package#TOC_6.): The trick is to create a new, empty `image.NRGBA` and then to "draw" the original image into the NRGBA image:

```
import "image/draw"

...

src := ...image to be converted...
b := src.Bounds()
m := image.NewNRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, b.Dx(), b.Dy()))
draw.Draw(m, m.Bounds(), src, b.Min, draw.Src)
```

Comment: Wow that's weird, since when you examine `png.Decode()` return value, it is an `image` but in the debug panel you can see it has a `data *image.NRGBA` member.
Where is that member coming from and how can one access it?

Comment: @Petruza I believe the `Draw` function is clever, and does something efficient when the source already has the correct format.  If you are sure that your source image is NRGBA, you could just use a type assertion: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15